# How to retrieve raster data in GeoMesa with a single query given tempospatial search criteria

Tags: geomesa

According to [How are GeoTIFFs persisted in GeoMesa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46939526/how-are-geotiffs-persisted-in-geomesa)

```
GeoMesa's raster data is indexed by spatial extent solely.
```

Can I also save time info with the raster data? Else, for each raster I will have to persist another record holding its time info. Therefore, in order to retrieve my raster using a tempospatial query (is WMS capable for this? according to [1] it seems to be) I will have to retrieve both files; this means for x raster ==> x+1 GeoMesa hits (retrievals).

[1] http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/time.html

Answer (score 0):

Currently, no, you cannot save time info with the raster data.

WMS does support time and time range queries.  That capability isn't wired up completely in the AccumuloRasterStore.

As an alternative, GeoMesa does allow for storing blobs and creating pointers to them on the way. The GeoMesa BlobStore doesn't allow for WMS access, but it is a nifty, extensible capability.

Comment: Sad to hear this. Does putRaster() save raster data in BlobStore? If not what is the difference? Note: :putRaster() is described on  https://github.com/locationtech/geomesa/blob/master/geomesa-accumulo/geomesa-accumulo-raster/src/test/scala/org/locationtech/geomesa/raster/data/AccumuloRasterStoreQueryIntegratedTest.scala

Comment: Well, that's one of the benefits of open source!  If you'd like to add (or fund) the capability, you can.;)

The blobstore is different from the raster store.  (http://www.geomesa.org/documentation/user/blobstore.html)