# Storing GeoTIFFs in GeoMesa

Tags: geomesa

I want to store in GeoMesa GeoTIFFs and retrieve them with WMS. The idea is saving them in BlobStore according to http://www.geomesa.org/documentation/user/blobstore.html by parsing their spatial info using GDAL (http://www.gdal.org/formats_list.html).
But it seems that you cannot query with WMS data peristed in BlobStore ([How to retrieve raster data in GeoMesa with a single query given tempospatial search criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47242572/how-to-retrieve-raster-data-in-geomesa-with-a-single-query-given-tempospatial-se/47270696#47270696)).

Moreover, what if I want to have temporal info for my GeoTIFFs? Where should I store them?

Answer (score 0):

The blobstore does not support WMS.  The blobstore has a pluggable indexing module which allows for handling temporal information in an application specific manner.